# changing a control style with dependency in another control

Tags: qt, stylesheet

I would like to affect one widget(pane) only if the first tab in the tab bar is selected.

I tried something like this in my stylesheet:

```
QTabBar::tab:first:selected

{ 

QTabWidget::pane:border-top-left-radius: 0px;

 }
```

it didn't work. can you suggest me an alternative?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use only the QStylesheets? or are you OK with doing it in code?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a custom dynamic property on the widget to style when the tab selection changes.
On creation, set the property to false:

```
tabWidget->setProperty("firstSelected", false);
```

In a slot reacting to tab switch:

```
const bool firstSelected = ...
tabWidget->setProperty("firstSelected", firstSelected);
```

In the style sheet:

```
QTabWidget[firstSelected="true"] { ... }

QTabWidget[firstSelected="false"] { ... }
```

If that doesn't work, you can change the stylesheet manually in the slot listening to tab changes.